# Mql4 Color Transparency in Rectangle Object

Tags: mql4

Is it possible to add in color transparency to an object?  Eg.  I want to make a rectangle and instead of making it while #ffffff i wanted to make it transparent.

I was wondering if anyone can show me some example code to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not immediately obvious from the [ObjectCreate](https://docs.mql4.com/constants/objectconstants/enum_object/obj_rectangle) description. You have to make the object appear in the foreground and disable the filling as per the following code:

```
ObjectCreate(0,"Rectangle",OBJ_RECTANGLE,0,Time[10],Open[10],Time[0],Open[0]);
ObjectSetInteger(0,"Rectangle",OBJPROP_COLOR,clrBlack);
ObjectSetInteger(0,"Rectangle",OBJPROP_FILL,false);
ObjectSetInteger(0,"Rectangle",OBJPROP_BACK,false);
```

Comment: How about making it semi transparent? this way its just making an outline border.. it would be great if we can make it semi transparent, or have a rasterised diagonal lines or something

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OBJ_RECTANGLE_LABEL` instead of `OBJ_RECTANGLE` to get the transparent effect.